# How to sort dataset in VB .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, datatable, dataset

I am working on a code, where i need to sort the data received in dataset through database by date (which later is exported in the excel sheet and data should be sorted in the excel sheet by date).

Following is the code snippet i used to sort.

```
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dte As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable()
       dte.DefaultView.Sort = "DATE_START ASC" // Using this to sort
       dte.DefaultView.ToTable()
```

dte.DefaultView.Sort = "DATE_DUE ASC" is returning the true value, but still dte returns unsorted data. Not sure whats wrong here. Is there any alternate approach to sort the data by date?

Comment: When you sort the `DefaultView`, you are doing just that: sorting the `DefaultView`. That has exactly zero effect on the `DataTable` itself so if you then loop over the `Rows` collection then you'll see no difference. You have to loop over the `DefaultView` to see the effect of the sort. Each item will be a `DataRowView` rather than a `DataRow`, but you can probably treat them the same way regardless.

Comment: By the way, is there really any point calling `ToTable`? Unless you're binding that `DataTable` and need to see the data unsorted, get rid of that part. Simply set `ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort` and then loop over `ds.Tables(0).DefaultView`.

Comment: Also, is there actually any point to your `DataSet`? Does it contain any other `DataTables`? If not then why create it at all? Why not just create the `DataTable` you need and use that directly?

Comment: In the code you posted, you first create a copy of the existing `DataTable`, then sort the `DefaultView` of that copy, then you create a copy of the sorted data but you don't do anything with it. If you assign the result of that last `ToTable` to another variable or even back to `dte`, you can then access the sorted data via that variable.

Comment: What could it possibly mean to sort a Dataset. Do you want the tables in the Dataset to be sorted in alphabetical order by table name? No, you want to sort a DataTable. You might want to edit your title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ORDER BY

```
dte.DefaultView.Sort = "ORDER BY DATE_START ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.Select ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_)) passing nothing in the filter expression, your column in the sort, and then call CopyToDataTable ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable)) on the result:

```vb
Dim dte = ds.Tables(0).Select("", "DATE_START ASC").CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already sorting the data correctly, so you must just be accessing it incorrectly.

```vb
'Don't create a DataSet that you don't need.
'If all you need is a DataTable, create a DataTable.
Dim table As New DataTable

'Configure and populate table here.

'Sort the associated view.
table.DefaultView.Sort = "DATE_START"

'This will display the data unsorted, because the DataTable itself is not sorted.
For Each row As DataRow in table.Rows
    Console.WriteLine($"{row("ID")}, {row("DATE_START"}")
Next

'This will display the data sorted.
For Each view As DataRowView in table.DefaultView
    Console.WriteLine($"{view("ID")}, {view("DATE_START"}")
Next
```